# Inserting specific String into empty Cells in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

**Objective:** Fill all empty cells in a Worksheet with a string ("/N").

**Problem:** During the code run, I keep getting a type mismatch for some reason. **This error appears on the line:**

```
If Worksheets("Comp").Cells(lRow, lColumn) = "" Then
```

**Question:** What am I doing wrong, is there a way to fix it?

**Obs1:** My worksheet contains 5 thousand rows and 40 columns. First 3 rows are headers (identifiers) and first 3 columns always have data.

**Obs2:** The worksheet has different types of data (numbers, strings, dates)

**Code:**

```
Sub n_slasher()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
Dim lRow As Long, lColumn As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim w As Workbook

Set w = ThisWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'find date limits
LastRow = Worksheets("Comp").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = Worksheets("Comp").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For lColumn = 4 To LastColumn
            For lRow = 3 To LastRow
                If Worksheets("Comp").Cells(lRow, lColumn) = "" Then
                    Worksheets("Comp").Cells(lRow, lColumn) = "\N"     
                End If 
            Next lRow
        Next lColumn

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Type mismatch on which line of execution?

Comment: when you get the error find the cell that is causing it, it probably has an error in it, ie #N/A,#Value,...

Comment: Maybe just `Worksheets("Comp").Range("D3", Worksheets("Comp").Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks).Value2 = "\N"`

Comment: @Marc The error is in the line If Worksheets("Comp").Cells(lRow, lColumn) = "" Then

Comment: @ScottCraner I will check again, but this worksheet was created with a "Paste as Values" procedure. It only has values or empty cells (no formulas or errors).

Comment: What if you put a `.Value` after `Cells()` in `If Worksheets("Comp").Cells(lRow, lColumn) = "" Then Worksheets("Comp").Cells(lRow, lColumn) = "\N"`, so instead of `.Cells(lRow, lColumn)`, you'll have `.Cells(lRow, lColumn).Value` in both lines...

Comment: @Rory Seems very simple, but it returns the error: "No cells are found".

Comment: Then the cells aren't actually empty. I'd suggest using an array.

Comment: @dot.Py Just tried it, same error.

Comment: @Rory I will try that now, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Even with copy an paste just values if the cell that was copied returned an error the error persists and will throw the type mismatch on that line.  Run your code when it breaks, find the cell that is being referenced.  What is it's value?

Comment: @ScottCraner It stops at lRow 1079, lColumn 35, in this cell I have a string ("EJS"). Very peculiar.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are looking at cell AI1079?

Comment: @ScottCraner At first I did, but since the code starts counting from lrow 3 and lcolumn 4, I also checked all the cells in that area (20 rows up and down, 10 columns right and left). They all have data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version using an array

```
Sub n_slasher()

    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
    Dim lRow As Long, lColumn As Long
    Dim ws                    As Worksheet
    Dim w                     As Workbook
    Dim data

    Set w = ThisWorkbook

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
    Set ws = Worksheets("Comp")
    'find date limits

    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        data = .Range("D3", .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Value2

        For lRow = 1 To UBound(data)
            For lColumn = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
                If Not IsError(data(lRow, lColumn)) Then If Len(data(lRow, lColumn)) = 0 Then data(lRow, lColumn) = "\N"
            Next lColumn
        Next lRow
        .Range("D3", .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Value2 = data
    End With

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it, it runs without error, but nothing in the worksheet changes. It stays the same. Very peculiar.

Comment: That confirms that there is *something* in the cells. Where did the data come from?

Comment: I created it myself, from data I got online. it is very peculiar, because the cells are apparently empty. I will upload a picture to the OP.

Comment: Maybe try Trim on the cells during the test? just shooting in the dark, but it may also be some other unprintable character that trim may not remove.

Comment: A picture won't be much use if you can't see any data. Select a "blank" cell and from the Immediate window run `msgbox ascw(activecell)`

Comment: @Rory Just tried that, it returns an empty messagebox.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible. You should either see a number, or an error message if the cell is actually blank. Can you put a workbook somewhere?

Comment: @Rory You were right, it turns out, and I completely missed it, that the "empty" cells had a "space" in them. So, instead of the len part of your code, I used If data(lRow, lColumn) = " ". Problem Solved. Also, my original code was giving an error because there was a = sign, that it was accounting as a calculation, where it should have been "=".

Comment: If they all had just a space in, then: `Worksheets("Comp").Range("D3", Worksheets("Comp").Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Replace " ", "\N", xlWhole` should suffice.